# YouTubePlayerView fullscreen snaps video to top

Tags: ios, iphone, video, swift3, youtube

I am using the YouTubePlayerView library for swift to display a YouTube player in my iOS 10 app. I am able to properly playback a YouTube full screen video in portrait and landscape mode within a view controller. Quite often the video "snaps" to the top of the screen instead of playing at the center in portrait. So, instead of this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

My constraints are set correctly, leading, trailing, bottom and top all set to the parent view (the controller view actually) of the YouTubePlayerView. I suspect that this might not be a layout issue, not a native one at least. Instead I believe it is a UIWebView issue. Currently the playerParams are set like:

```
fileprivate func playerParameters() -> YouTubePlayerParameters {

    return [
        "height": "100%" as AnyObject,
        "width": "100%" as AnyObject,
        "events": playerCallbacks() as AnyObject,
        "playerVars": playerVars as AnyObject
    ]
}
```

which is the default for the player.

But how do I properly layout the player within the webview to present the video centered vertically while on portrait?

Thanks

p.s. Setting the player mode to inline is not going to cut it as I want to have a "done" button available to dismiss the video view.

Answer (score 0):

Since YT youtube player render html inside the `WebView`, modifying CSS will do the trick.

In **YTPlayer.html** add the following code inside the `style` tag

```
div {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```